# Parallel.For vs ThreadPool and async/await

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

I'm trying to process 5000 files in an async manner without growing the Threadpool unrestricted. The `Parallel.For` loop however, is not giving me a consistent correct answer (count comes up short), while the Task.Run is.

What am I doing wrong in the `Parallel.For` loop that is causing these incorrect answers?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static volatile int count = 0;
    static volatile int total = 0;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Parallel.For(0, 5000, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 },
            async (index) =>
            {
                string filePath = $"C:\\temp\\files\\out{index}.txt";
                var bytes = await ReadFileAsync(filePath);
                Interlocked.Add(ref total, bytes.Length);
                Interlocked.Increment(ref count);
            });
        Console.WriteLine(count);
        Console.WriteLine(total);

        count = 0;
        total = 0;
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        foreach (int index in Enumerable.Range(0, 5000))
        {
            tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                string filePath = $"C:\\temp\\files\\out{index}.txt";
                var bytes = await ReadFileAsync(filePath);
                Interlocked.Add(ref total, bytes.Length);
                Interlocked.Increment(ref count);
            }));
        }
        Task.WhenAll(tasks).Wait();
        Console.WriteLine(count);
        Console.WriteLine(total);
    }
    public static async Task<byte[]> ReadFileAsync(string filePath)
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[4096];
        using (var sourceStream = new FileStream(filePath,
                FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read,
                bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true))
        {
            await sourceStream.ReadAsync(bytes, 0, 4096);
        };
        return bytes;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about your desired outcomes. What do you mean _growing the thread pool unrestricted_ In your second sample your queueing 5000 tasks but it doesn't mean they're ready run. In any event the volatile is only needed without an interlock. Also, what value of `count` are you expecting vs actual in both instances?

Comment: It seems to me that reading the entire file just to get its length is highly inefficient. `new FileInfo(somePath).Length` would be much more efficient (albeit not asynchronous... however, the setup for `new FileStream` also does a bunch of synchronous stuff including getting the length, so it's no loss)

Comment: Don't mix `Parallel.For/ForEach` with `async/await`

Comment: @JSteward I was expecting count to be 5000 in both cases and I wanted to control the number of threads running in the threadpool. The threadpool adds new threads every 500 ms when all threads are busy, if I'm correct.

Comment: @spender The snippet above is just an example to demonstrate the issue, not the actual code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Parallel.For` is not `async` aware.

As such, the `Parallel.For` is not performing as you expect. Because the task generated by the async lambda is not waited for, all of the iterations will complete in the time it takes to **create** the tasks, not complete them.

After your `Parallel.For`, a number of iterations will still have a pending task that is not yet complete, and therefore, your additions to `count` and `total` have not yet completed.

Stephen Toub has implemented an async version of Parallel.ForEach. ([ForEachAsync](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/03/05/implementing-a-simple-foreachasync-part-2/)) The implementation is as follows:

```
public static Task ForEachAsync<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int dop, Func<T, Task> body)
{
    return Task.WhenAll(
        from partition in Partitioner.Create(source).GetPartitions(dop)
        select Task.Run(async delegate {
            using (partition)
                while (partition.MoveNext())
                    await body(partition.Current);
        }));
}
```

So you might rewrite your loop:

```
Enumerable.Range(0, 5000).ForEachAsync(10, async (index)=>{
   //$$$
});
```

Comment: Interesting, I had no idea you could not combine Parallel.For with async. `Because the task generated by the async lambda is not waited for, all of the iterations will complete in the time it takes to create the tasks, not complete them.` Doesn't the Task.WhenAll wait for all tasks to be completed though?

Comment: @MvdD It does, though it waits only for first "exit" from `async` methods. "Return" back to the `async` may not happen.