# Raising events during Tasks causing Cross-Thread Exception

Tags: c#, async-await

I wrote a Client/Server async classes which works fine in the console. I created a WinForm project for the server which subscribes to an event thrown by the server when there is a `.Pending()` connection and writes some messages into a textbox - which causes a Cross-Thread exception. The exception does not surprise me, however I am looking for a way to invoke that event without causing this exception, without handling it on the GUI/Control with `.InvokeRequired` and `.Invoke` - if that is even possible?

The server is started like that:

```
Server server = new Server(PORT);
server.RunAsync();
```

in `.RunAsync()` i just iterate over the network devices and set them to listening and invoke an event that the server has started, this also writes into the GUI however without any issue.

```
public async Task RunAsync()
    {
        GetNetworkDevicesReady(Port);

        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Parallel.ForEach(networkListeners, (listener) =>
            {
                Write.Info($"LISTENING ON {listener.LocalEndpoint}");
                listener.Start();
            });
        });
        IsRunning = true;

        OnServerStarted?.Invoke(this, networkListeners.Where(l=>l.Active).ToList());

    }
```

The code below is registered on the `Form.Load` event and does not cause a Cross-Thread exception when writing "SERVER STARTED" in the textbox.

```
server.OnServerStarted += (s, a) =>
        {
            consoleWindow1.Event("SERVER STARTED", $"{Environment.NewLine}\t{string.Join($"{Environment.NewLine}\t", a.Select(x=>x.LocalEndpoint))}");

            consoleWindow1.Event("WAITING FOR PENDING CONNECTIONS");
            server.WaitForConnectionsAsync();
        };
```

And this is the code which runs indefinite until a cancellation token is triggered:

```
public async Task WaitForConnectionsAsync()
    {
        waitingForConnectionsToken = new CancellationTokenSource();

        await (waitinfConnectionTaks=Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
        {
            while (!waitingForConnectionsToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                foreach (var listener in networkListeners)
                {
                    if (waitingForConnectionsToken.IsCancellationRequested) break;

                    if (!listener.Active)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (listener.Pending())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            TcpClient connection = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
                            //TODO: need to send it synchronised, since this causes a Cross-Thread when using WinForms
                            OnPendingConnection?.Invoke(this, connection);

                        }
                        catch (ObjectDisposedException x)
                        {
                            Write.Error(x.ToString());
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }));
    }
```

I know I can use the textbox `.InvokeRequired` and `.Invoke` on the GUI but I have the feeling that the server should throw the event in a way the GUI doesn't cause a Cross-Thread exception.

Is there a way to invoke the eventhandler in that "infinite task" without causing this exception?

Comment: "but I have the feeling that the server should throw the event in a way the GUI doesn't cause a Cross-Thread exception" - In non-UI contexts, synchronising to a single thread could slow things down. Are you sure this is what you want to do?

Comment: async/await will synchronize to the calling synchronization context after await if possible and you did not use ConfigureAwait(false). But each listener is started inside the Parallel.ForEach which also runs inside a task worker thread. So there is no sync context anymore the listener can sync to, thus you get the cross thread exception

Comment: Don't use `Parallel.Forxxx` with `async/await`

Comment: `I am looking for a way to invoke that event without causing this exception, without handling it on the GUI/Control with .InvokeRequired and .Invoke` If that's what you want, this is the purpose of the synchronization context. Capture the current synchronization context in `RunAsync`, then use it in `WaitForConnectionsAsync` to execute the event handlers. But I'd take John's advice in consideration first

Comment: "server should throw the event in a way ..." could only happen if the server used  something like SomeControl.Invoke().  Binding it to WinForms and slowing it down.

Comment: @MickyD any elaboration why? Is that doubling up like creating a thread for a thread?

Comment: @John  & Kevin  of course I wouldn't want it to slow down (not at least in the server class). After sleeping and reading the comments - a solution would be to not create an infinite loop around it and making it awaitable. After that has completed, invoking the event and then re-creating / starting the task again (until some exit/stop condition)

Comment: @bommelding yes, however I wanted to avoid passing in any forms/controls. I might have somehow found out through the invocation list where the call came from and check if it was a control/form and then call Invoke on it.. but again I hoped to avoid that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11565317/585968 and https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2009/05/26/does-parallel-for-use-one-task-per-iteration/ and the big one https://stackoverflow.com/a/42450935/585968

Comment: @MickyD thanks for the links, will go through them.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments and a good portion of sleep I solved my issue by changing the `WaitForConnectionsAsync` to the following code:

```
List<TcpClient> connections = new List<TcpClient>();
public async Task WaitForConnectionsAsync()
{
        await (waitinfConnectionTaks = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
        {
           //REMOVED LOOP
           // while (!waitingForConnectionsToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                foreach (var listener in networkListeners)
                {
                    if (waitingForConnectionsToken.IsCancellationRequested) break;

                    if (!listener.Active)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (listener.Pending())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            TcpClient connection = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();

                            //RETAIN CONNECTIONS IN A LIST
                            connections.Add(connection);
                        }
                        catch (ObjectDisposedException x)
                        {
                            Write.Error(x.ToString());
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }));
        //ITERATE OVER CONNECTIONS
        foreach (var connection in connections)
        {
            //INVOKE EVENT
            OnPendingConnection?.Invoke(this, connection);
        }
        //CLEAR THE LIST
        connections.Clear();

        //RESTART THE TASK
        if(!waitingForConnectionsToken.IsCancellationRequested)
           WaitForConnectionsAsync();
    }
```

So Basically i am catching all pending connections into a list, once the work has completed, I run over the list, fire the event with each connection, clear the list and then start the task again. This code change doesn't throw the Cross-Thread exception anymore.

An improvement i could add now is to accept a collection in the event instead a single connection.

If you have any improvements or better practice suggestions, please let me know.